# Calculate variance of $A + 2B$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I got two discrete random variables A and B that are independent of each other and I have to calculate $var(A + 2B).$

Would that then just be $var(A + 2B) = var(A) + var(2B)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

$$Var(A+2B) = Var(A)+Var(2B)+2cov(A, 2B)$$

but $cov(A,2B)=0$ as $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Also, $Var(2B)=2^2Var(B)$

Answer (score 2):

Actually the variance of multiples of two random variables can be shown to be:

$$Var(aX + bY) = a^2Var(X) + b^2Var(Y) + 2abCoVar(X,Y)$$

But since they are independent then $CoVar(X,Y) = 0$ so

$$Var(aX + bY) = a^2Var(X) + b^2Var(Y)$$ for independent $X,Y$

Answer (score 1):

What you have written so far is correct.
To finish, you will want to use the fact that $\operatorname{Var}(cB)=c^2 \operatorname{Var}(B)$ for any scalar $c$.